# How to find name all rows from a table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-5.5

Here is my function .Earlier it was working in a very better way but now a day it is not working well .

```
function table_rows()
    {

    $sql="SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='check_db' AND `TABLE_NAME`='tbl_details'";
    $result= mysql_query($sql);

    return $result;
    }
```

The function results..Something like this .I want only field names.

```
COLUMN_NAME
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=id&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=fnme&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=lnme&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=age&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=dob&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=mail&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&amp;field=ads&amp;token=8a5756ad27bfde74d341bfed684767e5
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first, `mysql_` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or PDO

second, you are only executing the sql query, but not fetching any data. Try the code below. Note that $con is the variable to connect to db. You should change it to your own

(Edited)
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

```
function db () {
    static $con;
    if ($con===NULL){ 
        $con = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    }
    return $con;
}

function table_rows()
  {
    $con = db();
    $sql="SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='check_db' AND `TABLE_NAME`='tbl_details'";

    $query= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result= mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $result;
 }
```

Comment: $con is out of scope

Comment: @nogad what do u mean

Comment: variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: oh dang, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: dont ever use global unless there is no other option.

Comment: @nogad Thanks! I ve always only worked with symfony in php, didnt know using globals for db vars was a bad practice.

Comment: Edited my answer @MERINSUNNY